# How can I monitor changing window sizes in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my mobile web app with Vue, I want to hide my footer when the soft keyboard pops. So I have a little function to test the ratio of window height to window width...

```
showFooter(){
    return h / w > 1.2 || h > 560;
}
```

...and I declare window.innerHeight/window.innerWidth in my data.

```
    data: { h: window.innerHeight, w: window.innerWidth }
```

Trouble is, when window.innerHeight changes, my h property doesn't get the new value. How can I watch window.innerHeight ?

Comment: Instead of doing it based on window width / height could you not do it on input / select / textarea focus?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

To get the current window height of your browser as it changes, use this script:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      windowHeight: window.innerHeight
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      window.addEventListener('resize', this.onResize);
    })
  },

  beforeDestroy() { 
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.onResize); 
  },

  methods: {  
    onResize() {
      this.windowHeight = window.innerHeight
    }
  }
});
```

To display the information, use:

```js
<div id="app">
 Current height: {{ windowHeight }}
</div>
```

Comment: you need   `windowHeight: window.height,` in your data function

Comment: Just a reminder to use something like
`beforeDestroy() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.onScrollFunction);
  }`
I emphasise the use of  it even more when it is a SPA.

Comment: @MarlonBarcarol why is this necessary?

Comment: It's necessary because as you move between components you'll wind up with 100s or 1000s of event listeners registered which will eat memory and slow the browser. Instead when a component is removed (destroyed) you want to remove any event listener related to that component since it's no longer needed.

Comment: Crucially - you need to do this because the listener is on the *window*, not the component that gets destroyed.

Comment: I'm sorry it took me this long to update my answer guys and thanks @MarlonBarcarol  for the addition

Comment: Just two things:
I think the methods:{} wrapper is missing from around onResize(). It should be:

methods: {
   onResize() {
   this.windowHeight = window.innerHeight
   }
}

And windowHeight should be window.innerHeight at initialisation instead of zero.

windowHeight: window.innerHeight

Comment: @Rich Thanks for the catch. I added `methods: {}` wrapper to `onResize(){}` but I didn't get the second part

Comment: @samayo When the app starts it displays - Window height: 0. However in reality the window height is not zero. For displaying the real height at start, windowHeight in data{...} can be window.innerHeight (instead zero).

Comment: @Rich Thank you! I added it 

Comment: Why is `$nextTick` necessary here?

Comment: Very usefull. Thanks!!!

Comment: The `beforeDestroy` lifecycle hook is deprecated. Use `beforeUnmount` instead.: `eslintvue/no-deprecated-destroyed-lifecycle`

Answer (score 46):

**VUE 2.7 and above**

In Vue 2.7+, you can create a composable that returns a reactive width and breakpoint name.

```javascript
import { computed, onMounted, onUnmounted, ref } from "vue"

export const useBreakpoints = () => {
  let windowWidth = ref(window.innerWidth)

  const onWidthChange = () => windowWidth.value = window.innerWidth
  onMounted(() => window.addEventListener('resize', onWidthChange))
  onUnmounted(() => window.removeEventListener('resize', onWidthChange))
  
  const type = computed(() => {
    if (windowWidth.value < 550) return 'xs'
    if (windowWidth.value >= 550 && windowWidth.value < 1200) return 'md'
    else return 'lg' // Fires when windowWidth.value >= 1200
  })

  const width = computed(() => windowWidth.value)

  return { width, type }
}
```

You can use it in the setup method of your components.

```javascript
const { width, type } = useBreakpoints()
```

Note: If you would like this simplicity and also performance is crucial, you would want this computed only once. In that case, implement them using effect scopes, so that the events get added/removed only in that scope. Libraries like vueuse might have this taken care of, out-of-the-box.

Else, do this once in a scope close to the entry point, such as `App.vue` and commit it to your global state management solution or provide/inject it (please don't, just import the composable from a library).

Comment: This did not work for me – I received the following error:
`10:25  error  Expected to return a value in computed function  vue/return-in-computed-property`

Comment: It has to be a eslint rule. Eslint is not able to infer that there will always be a return value here. Eslint is notorious for these cases. You can safely add an "eslint ignore" for this line/file.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying! Would there also be a way to import this utility function into a component that is not written with setup() (uses Options) ?

Comment: It has to be used in a setup method. You could make an new setup method, call the function and return it. It is very normal to use both composition api and options api in the same component.

Comment: Hello, I am trying to get this to work in my project and am having a bit of trouble understanding how to use this plugin. 
I really am just looking for the width, but I've used the whole bit of code you wrote.
I've offloaded the top bit of code into a `window-width.ts` file and am trying to access them in another component. 
I'm not really understanding the destructuring used in your `const { width, type } = useBreakpoints()` 
Im still a bit new to Vue and using plugins so maybe it's just a fundamental misunderstanding, but if you have any ideas I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Try console.log(useBreakpoints()). It will log an object with width and type as keys. That is what's being destructured.

Comment: Generally, when you run into cases where eslint complains about an expected return property after a set of conditions that cover all possibilities, you've used one-too-many conditionals. In this case, where we only have three buckets for window size to fall into, we only need to check whether the size falls into the first two– if it doesn't, it will _always_ be in the third. Checking all 3 makes for a superfluous conditional check, and makes for more confusing code that implies a fallthrough is possible at first glance.

Answer (score 19):

The above answer didn't work for me. Instead, I used:

```javascript
mounted() {
  window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    this.windowHeight = window.innerHeight
  })
}
```

Comment: something is off with your brackets. `window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
        this.windowHeight = window.innerHeight
      });`

Answer (score 15):

For those already using Vuetify, you can just watch `this.$vuetify.breakpoint.width` or `this.$vuetify.breakpoint.height` for changes in the viewport's dimensions.

[Vuetify breakpoint docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/breakpoints/)

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for. You can also use `xs`,`sm`,`md` instead of checking the width (check the linked doc)

Answer (score 9):

This is probably really too late but if you want a much more simpler approach you can do npm installation https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-window-size
and `import windowWidth from 'vue-window-size';`

Or this with composition api

```
    setup() {
        const windowSize = ref(window.innerWidth)
        onMounted(() => {
            window.addEventListener('resize', () => {windowSize.value = window.innerWidth} )
        })
        onUnmounted(() => {
            window.removeEventListener('resize', () => {windowSize.value = window.innerWidth})
        })
        return { 
            windowSize
        }
    }
```

Comment: Never too late!

Comment: You need to create a function and use it in listeners. In your example, you add listener and remove listener to different functions, i.e. removing the event will not work. `window.addEventListener('resize', func)`, `window.removeEventListener('resize', func)`

Answer (score 1):

My answer might be late but none of the above worked for me so here is what I found on this topic ! :)

https://codepen.io/sethdavis512/pen/EvNKWw

HTML :

```
<div id="app">
    <section class="section has-text-centered">
        <h1 class="title is-1">
            Your Window
        </h1>
        <h3 class="title is-3">
            Width: {{ window.width }} px<br/>
            Height: {{ window.height }} px
        </h3>
        <p class="has-text-white">
            &uarr;<br/>
            &larr; resize window &rarr;<br/>
            &darr;
        </p>
    </section>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
$top-color: yellow;
$bottom-color: tomato;

html, body, #app, section.section {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient($top-color, $bottom-color);
    background: -o-linear-gradient($top-color, $bottom-color);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient($top-color, $bottom-color);
    background: linear-gradient($top-color, $bottom-color);
}

section.section {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.title {
    color: white;
}
```

JS:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        window: {
            width: 0,
            height: 0
        }
    },
    created() {
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
        this.handleResize();
    },
    destroyed() {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
    },
    methods: {
        handleResize() {
            this.window.width = window.innerWidth;
            this.window.height = window.innerHeight;
        }
    }
});
```