# Vue watch syntax ${somevariable}. Could someone please explain?

Tags: vuejs2, watch

[How can I use window size in Vue? (How do I detect the soft keyboard?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47219272/how-can-i-use-window-size-in-vue-how-do-i-detect-the-soft-keyboard)

The link above is an excellent answer but I don't understand what this (`) mark is and why the values for newHeight, oldHeight are passed in. Also why this syntax ${somevariable} in the watcher works.

windowHeight(newHeight, oldHeight)
this.txt = `it changed to ${newHeight} from ${oldHeight}`;
...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "backtick" syntax is not Vue specific, but it's a javascript language feature called *Template literals*. It's quite easy though: when you write a string like this:

```js
const what = "world";
const salutation = `Hello ${what}`;
```

the value of `salutation` will be "Hello world". When the expression is evaluated, the interpreter swaps the `${what}` with the actual content of the `what` variable.

You can learn more about [template literals on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

In the linked answer, it's used as a simple debug method to show what's going on.

Comment: Thanks Pongi. Excellent explanation.