# Vue.js get screen size like CSS media queries

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-composition-api

The current method that I am using right now to get the screen size is:

```
export const state = () => ({
  deviceType: window.innerWidth <= 600 ? 'mobile' : 'desktop',
})

export const getters = {
  getDeviceType(state) {
    return state.deviceType
  }
}
```

The **problem** with this is my website **needs to be refreshed to see the changes** that I set that should appear only on mobile.

I've read about using `window.addEventListener..` being able to solve this issue as it constantly triggers a function when the screen resizes.

But I am looking for a more straight forward way, ideally using **computed** or **watcher** on this. I think this is not a good way, using window.innerWidth, so any recommended way would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: which vue version are you using?

Comment: Sry forgot to mention. It's vue3

Answer (score 5):

this via computed works fine for me:
[How can I use window size in Vue? (How do I detect the soft keyboard?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47219272/how-can-i-use-window-size-in-vue-how-do-i-detect-the-soft-keyboard)

It always updates itself as soon as the window size changes, moreover, like in css the breakpoint designation is indicated.

```html
<template>
  <h1>{{ type + ": " + width }}</h1>
</template>

<script setup>
import { computed, onMounted, onUnmounted, ref } from "vue"

function useBreakpoints() {
  let windowWidth = ref(window.innerWidth)

  const onWidthChange = () => windowWidth.value = window.innerWidth
  onMounted(() => window.addEventListener('resize', onWidthChange))
  onUnmounted(() => window.removeEventListener('resize', onWidthChange))

  const type = computed(() => {
    if (windowWidth.value < 550) return 'xs'
    if (windowWidth.value >= 550 && windowWidth.value < 1200) return 'md'
    if (windowWidth.value >= 1200) return 'lg'
    return null; // This is an unreachable line, simply to keep eslint happy.
  })

  const width = computed(() => windowWidth.value)

  return { width, type }
}

const { width, type } = useBreakpoints()
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this solution with Vue 3 and TypeScript. It is convenient, easy to use and very performant because it will only attach one window resize listener no matter how many component instances use the device info.

The only issue is that you have to manually align the media breaks in your css with the breaks defined here.

```js
import { reactive } from 'vue'

export enum DeviceSize { xs, s, m, l, xl }

export type DeviceInfo = {
    windowWidth: number,
    size: DeviceSize,
}

const calcSize = (width: number): DeviceSize => {
    if (width < 640) return DeviceSize.xs
    if (width < 1024) return DeviceSize.s
    if (width < 1280) return DeviceSize.m
    if (width < 2048) return DeviceSize.l
    return DeviceSize.xl
}

const deviceInfo = reactive({
    windowWidth: window.innerWidth,
    size: DeviceSize.xs,
})

deviceInfo.size = calcSize(window.innerWidth)

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    const width = window.innerWidth
    deviceInfo.windowWidth = width
    deviceInfo.size = calcSize(width)
})

export const useDevice = (): DeviceInfo => {
    return deviceInfo
}

export default useDevice
```

To use this in a component:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
  import { useDevice, DeviceSize } from './useDevice'

  const device = useDevice()
</script>

<template>
  <div v-if="device.size > DeviceSize.s">Some large screen content</div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I combined both bikeman868 and Jannik Buscha answers to:

```
export enum MediaQuery { xs = 420, sm = 640, md = 768, lg = 1024, xl = 1280, '2xl' = 1440, '3xl' = 1600, '4xl' = 1920 }

export function useBreakpoints() {
    const windowWidth = ref(window.innerWidth);

    const onWidthChange = () => (windowWidth.value = window.innerWidth);
    onMounted(() => window.addEventListener('resize', onWidthChange));
    onUnmounted(() => window.removeEventListener('resize', onWidthChange));

    const mediaQuery = computed(() => {
        for (const query of Object.keys(MediaQuery)) {
            if (windowWidth.value < MediaQuery[query]) {
                return MediaQuery[query];
            }
        }

        return MediaQuery['4xl'];
    });

    const width = computed(() => windowWidth.value);

    return { width, mediaQuery };
}
```

And use it so:

```
const { mediaQuery } = useBreakpoints();

if (mediaQuery.value !== MediaQuery.xs) {
    // Do something..
});

if (mediaQuery.value < MediaQuery.lg) {
    // Do something..
});
```