# vuejs globalProperties windows screen size

Tags: vuejs3

I want to access it as global Properties, but as I mentioned below, I get an error on the console screen.
and `onMounted` does not perform `onUnmounted` functions

`[Vue warn]: onMounted is called when there is no active component instance to be associated with. Lifecycle injection APIs can only be used during execution of setup(). If you are using async setup(), make sure to register lifecycle hooks before the first await statement.at <App>`

`[Vue warn]: onUnmounted is called when there is no active component instance to be associated with. Lifecycle injection APIs can only be used during execution of setup(). If you are using async setup(), make sure to register lifecycle hooks before the first await statement.at <App>`
SidebarPlugin.js

```
import {computed, onMounted, onUnmounted, ref} from "vue";
const SidebarStore = ({
  showSidebar: ref(false),
  isMinimized: ref(false),
  windowWidth: ref(window.innerWidth),
  displaySidebar(value) {
    this.showSidebar.value = value;
  },
  useBreakpoints() {
    const onWidthChange = () => this.windowWidth.value = window.innerWidth
    onMounted(() => window.addEventListener('resize', onWidthChange))
    onUnmounted(() => window.removeEventListener('resize', onWidthChange))

    const type = computed(() => {
      if (this.windowWidth.value < 550) {return 'xs'}
      if (this.windowWidth.value >= 550 && this.windowWidth.value < 1200) {return 'md'}
      if (this.windowWidth.value >= 1200) {return 'lg'}
      return null;
    })
    const width = computed(() => this.windowWidth.value)

    return {width, type}
  }
})

const SidebarPlugin = {
  install(app, options) {
    if (options && options.sidebarLinks) {
      SidebarStore.sidebarLinks = options.sidebarLinks;
    }
    app.config.globalProperties.$sidebar = SidebarStore
    app.provide('sidebar', SidebarStore)
  }
};

export default SidebarPlugin;
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63944126/19329721)

Comment: So what should I do in this situation? Can you continue over my `.js` data

Comment: yes it worked for me but it would be great if it showed the only real value

Comment: I couldn't find the first work you did :S did you remove it

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your approach:

1. when vue plugins are added to an app instance, the app has not yet been mounted, so you can't use `onMounted` or `onUnmounted` there. They can only be used inside `setup`.
2. Using `resize` event to track the current responsiveness interval is bad for performance. Instead, one should use `window.matchMedia(mediaQueryString)`. The entity returned by calling this function can be watched for `change` events. And it only runs the bound callback when the result of matching the media query has changed, not on every window `resize`. It's the same API powering the CSS media queries. It's really light and blazing fast.

---

I initially started coding an example but, somewhere along the way I decided to add presets for common frameworks' breakpoint sets, throw in a readme and wrap it up as a public plugin ([vue-responsiveness](https://github.com/andrei-gheorghiu/vue-responsiveness#readme)).

---

If you're curious about how the code looks like, [this file](https://github.com/andrei-gheorghiu/vue-responsiveness/blob/main/lib/vue-responsiveness.ts) does the heavy lifting.

In a nutshell:

- takes in an intervals config, (`key`: `min` dictionary), sorts them and creates actual intervals (with media query strings for each interval limit)
- then it creates a MediaQueryList from each media query string and places event listeners on their `change` event
- those event listeners update a `reactive()` object, called `matches`, made available app-wide as `$matches`.

---

[Basic working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-grass-93d5q4?file=/src/App.vue).

Relevant code:

```js
import { VueResponsiveness } from 'vue-responsiveness'

createApp(App)
  .use(VueResponsiveness, {
    sm: 0,
    md: 550,
    lg: 1200
  })
  .mount('#app')
```

```html
<div class="sidebar" v-if="$matches.md.min">Sidebar</div>
```

The global props are `$matches[key][type]` (with the `key`s defined by the config object), and where `type` can be `min`, `max` and `only` - all booleans (`only` is `true` when both `min` and `max` are `true`).

E.g: in the above example `$matches.sm.max` is `true` while the viewport width is below `550px`.

`$matches` is not trully global, it's app-wide (globals are discouraged in Vue 3). This means it will work with multiple apps in complex scenarios (I'm thinking several apps sharing stores in an Electron based environment, each displayed on a different screen, therefore each reacting to its own `$matches` - I actually had a client with these exact requirements not long ago, for a security monitoring system).

It's particularly light `968 B` gzipped (presets included) and as performant as possible (the bound listeners are only triggered when the media query result changes value, not on every `resize` event).
The event listeners are placed on the `MediaQueryList` instances, which means unmounting the app removes the associated listeners, so no events are left bound on `<body>` or `window` object.