# Set variable to true or false depending of screen width in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-composition-api

I'm working on a responsive navigation menu, currently, i finished the mobile view, but i realize, i have a problem:
for the desktop view, i want to hide the button that toggles the mobile navbar, and just show the navbar, but it doesn't show because the navbar is bound to a reactive variable with the "v-if" directive, my question is, how i'm gonna show the navbar?
I thought setting the variable true or false depending on the screen size, but i cannot make a method because of the click event that also change the variable value to toggle the menu nav in mobile screens. What approach can i take?  is it any way to remove the "v-if" on larger screens?
Thank you for your help.

```
//reactive variable==========================
const showUserDropdown = ref(false)

//=================mobile toggle button=====================
<div class="pt-1 text-right">
    <button class="text-right md:hidden" @click="showDropdown = !showDropdown">
         <Icon :name="showDropdown ? 'up' : 'menu'" class="w-6 h-6 inline-block fill-cyan-800" />
    </button>
</div>
//====================mobile nav==================
nav class="" v-if="showDropdown">
   <ul class="">
       <li v-for="(item, index) in menu" :key="item.id" class="pb-2">
             <Link>
                 <Icon :name="item.icon_name" class="w-5 h-5 mr-2 inline fill-slate-500" />
                 <span class="capitalize"> {{ item.name }}</span>
             </Link>
       </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

mobile: ========================
https://i.postimg.cc/3RCXGYX1/Screenshot-2023-03-13-at-14-23-42-Laravel.png

desktop: =============================

https://i.postimg.cc/TwXjhpDh/Screenshot-2023-03-13-at-14-24-03-Laravel.png

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47219272/how-can-i-use-window-size-in-vue-how-do-i-detect-the-soft-keyboard it looks pretty similar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I monitor changing window sizes in Vue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47219272/how-can-i-monitor-changing-window-sizes-in-vue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do this then the variable will update when the screen width changes and will not continually fire like a resize event will.

```js
<script setup>
const isMobile = ref('')
let mql

function handleMqlChange(e) {
  isMobile.value = e.matches
}

onMounted(() => {
  mql = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 1024px)')
  isMobile.value = mql.matches
  mql.addEventListener('change', handleMqlChange)
})

onUnmounted(() => {
  mql.removeEventListener('change', handleMqlChange)
})
</script>
```

You can then use a simple `v-if="isMobile"`. This will work when the page loads and also when the user changes the screen size, whether that be an orientation change on a mobile device or a browser tab resize.

Answer (score 0):

The global `window` variable has all the information you need regarding screen width.  Here is an example of what `window.screen` gives you.

```js
Screen {
  availHeight
  availLeft
  availTop
  availWidth
  colorDepth
  height
  isExtended
  onchange
  orientation: ScreenOrientation {
    angle
    onchange
    type
    [[Prototype]]: ScreenOrientation
  }
  pixelDepth
  width
  [[Prototype]]: Screen
}
```

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/orientation

Simply define reactive property to `window.screen.width` or `window.screen.availWidth` depending on your use case.